# Splash screen for iPhone 6 and greater in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, launchimage

I have already put the image in the Resources under iOS project-xamarin.

```
Default-667h@2x.png
```

But still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Info.plist if you are using Asset Catalogs, images or LauchScreen.xib like so:

[image]

If you set it to an asset catalog then add images to LaunchImage like so:

[image]

Hope this helps